# How to focus an input on subscriptionsReady using FlowRouter in Meteor

Tags: meteor, autofocus, flow-router

I'm currently getting used to using FlowRouter after a while using Iron Router and trying to set up some best practices. I'm subscribing to my collection at a template level.

Previously I've waited for a template to render using `onRendered` and then targeted my input field and applied `focus()`, however I am now trying to only show my template in Blaze when the subscriptions are ready using the following (please excuse the Jade but I think it's pretty clear in this case)

```
template(name="subjectNew")

  unless Template.subscriptionsReady
   +spinner
  else
   form
    input(type="text" name="name")
```

So the basic idea is that until the subscriptions are ready the spinner shows. The issue I'm having is that now even when the template renders, the focus won't apply. I've tried various methods of wrapping it in an `autorun` call but not sure the best way of trying to target the first field when combined with this approach?

```
Template.subjectNew.onRendered(function() {
  console.log('rendered');
  $('input').first().focus();
});
```

Is it possible?

Many thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `subjectNew` is considered *rendered* even when it is only showing the spinner. Just stick your:

```
form
input(type="text" name="name")
```

Into a separate template and then attach your focus code to the `onRendered` handler of that other template.

```
template(name="subjectNew")
  unless Template.subscriptionsReady
    +spinner
  else
    +myForm

template(name="myForm")  
  form
  input(type="text" name="name")
```

js:

```
Template.myForm.onRendered(function(){
  $('input').focus()
});
```

Comment: Thanks @michel that's a nice and elegant solution, although it does mean a fair few more templates scattered around.

Answer (score 2):

I think using an autorun would be a good approach but then you would have to employ [`Tracker.afterFlush()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-afterFlush) to wait to set the focus after the form is rendered.

Something like:

```
Template.subjectNew.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    if (this.subscriptionsReady()) {
      Tracker.afterFlush(() => $('input').first().focus());
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!